In which Brazilian accent is R pronounced as a voiceless velar fricative [x]?
The R in Portuguese can be pronounced in 6 different ways, depending on the dialect and the position of of the letter in the word:

American R [ɹ]
Spanish Rolling R [r]
Tap/Flap [ɾ]
French Guttural R [ʁ]
Voiceless Guttural R [h, χ, x]
Silent R

[Source]
I am talking about the voiceless guttural R, which has 3 variations. I am specifically interested in one of these variations, which is the voiceless velar fricative [x]. If you are unfamiliar with this sound, it is similar to the “ch” in Hebrew “Channukah”, the “ch” in Scots “loch”, and the “x” in Russian “хороший”.
I found 3 Wikipedia articles that mention this sound and the fact that it exists in Brazilian Portuguese in “some dialects”. These articles are Voiceless velar fricative, Portuguese phonology and Guttural R. However, none of these articles mentions any examples of dialects where the R is pronounced as a voiceless velar fricative.
So, in which Brazilian accent is R pronounced as a voiceless velar fricative [x]?

I think in Rio they say [x], but we do not differentiate between [x] and [h], so someone can say [x] one time and then say [h] another.

@Schilive Are you sure? I listened to some speakers from Rio and all I heard was [h].

https://grad.letras.ufmg.br/arquivos/monitoria/Aula%2002%20apoio.pdf see page 6: carro = [h] everywhere except Rio [x], True in initial and medial positions: rato and carro, for example.

The Brazilian dialect most notable for its [x] is the Fluminense, i.e., from the Rio de Janeiro state, as, I'd say, can be heard here.
But it won't always be what you hear, as discussed here and as Wikipedia describes:

[[x] in Fluminense happens] In free variation with [χ], [ʁ], [ħ] and [h] before voiceless consonants

So, for instance, I can't really notice any substantial difference when I listen to the two (supposedly different sounding) samples mentioned in your source:

listen to how Gal Costa pronounces Rio, morrendo, Redentor with [χ] in Samba do Avião, but João Gilberto uses [x].


Just edited the post to remove this sample, as I guess it's rather an example of the χ pronunciation.

I can definitely hear it in the first YouTube video which you linked, when she pronounced "porta" and "carta".

Consoante fricativa velar surda is heard in carro and corta. The Paulistas would pronounce that x differently in corta than the Cariocas.
